# What wavelengths to combine to get 488nm?

Tags: laser, wavelength

Is it possible to combine a blue and green lasers to get cyan? If I used 405nm and 532nm, would I get (405+532)/2= 468.5nm? Is this a correct calculation?

Comment: Do you want something that *looks* cyan, or something that has 468.5 nm as monochromatic wavelength? Also, your calculation is non-sensical.

Comment: @ACuriousMind My target is 488nm - this wave length "excites" a specific type of cells.

Comment: Then you need a laser that supplies 488nm, period.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the cells will respond to a broad range of wavelengths, maybe the 405 nm laser would work alone. However, if you want to compare your results to other studies that used 488 nm then you should better use the same wavelength.

Comment: @ACuriousMind That's not quite true.  It is possible to mix two different wavelengths and generate a new one using nonlinear optics.  It certainly doesn't produce a wavelength at the average though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is no.  Mixing a purplish (405 nm) and green (532 nm) laser does not produce a bluish beam at 468.5 nm.  If you were to shine both lasers into your eye (which you should never do), the resultant effect would look bluish though due to the [physiology of the human eye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_eye).

However, it is possible to mix two wavelengths of light to produce a new wavelength with the use of [nonlinear optical devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_optics).  The technique is known as [sum frequency generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum-frequency_generation) in which the resultant laser beam has a frequency which is given by the sum of the two frequencies which you are pumping it with.  As a simple example for your case you could take a laser at 976 nm and convert it to 488 nm (remember that $f=c/\lambda$) in which case the technique is given the special name [second harmonic generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-harmonic_generation).

As with many nonlinear phenomena, you have to drive these nonlinear devices very hard to get an appreciable amount of power at the new wavelength.  So, you would need to find a very intense laser or pair of lasers in order to get a reasonable amount of light at the new wavelength.

Comment: Interesting answer. Probably not what OP needs, but interesting.

Comment: Would not the second harmonic be 1952nm? I guess I need 244nm one?

Comment: @Naz The frequencies sum, not the wavelengths:  $f=c/\lambda$. Said another way, you combine two photons with energy $E$ to produce one photon with energy $2E$.

Comment: Right, my bad. Then for a $600 976nm laser diode vs a $5000 488nm laser diode the choice is obvious. I wonder how expensive it will be to beat out the second harmonic.

Comment: Nonlinear crystals aren't cheap, and you will have a difficult time getting much light out of one with a laser diode.  In the end it might still be cheaper (especially when you factor in time cost) to buy the proper laser.

Answer (score 0):

**Note** You should never, *ever* look at a laser. It can cause irreversible damage to your eyes, including blindness. Now for your answer.

## Yes-ish

It will appear to be something in between, as you can see from a [color wheel](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ab/RBG_color_wheel.svg/2000px-RBG_color_wheel.svg.png). However, you should note that this would be the color you see if you reflected the beam off of something.

It should be noted, however, that some other sensors will not be fooled by this. If you were to use a prism, for example, you could separate out the individual laser beams. A true cyan laser wouldn't get separated out by a prism. It only looks cyan (or whatever color you want to call it) to use because it stimulates the correct receptors in our eyes, and our brains translate that to be that color, not a superimposition of the two. (This is how we get colors like pink.)

Comment: I see. This is not for visual effects. There are types of cells that emit fluorescence if illuminated by 488nm. Thus, I will not be able to achieve this with wavelength combination?

Comment: Correct, the superposition of two lasers of two different frequencies is not the same as one laser operating at the average frequency of the two lasers.

Comment: @Naz Nope. If you need the 488nm light, you need 488 nm light. Not something that averages out to it.